# How do I randomize an array of sprites in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, shuffle

Everytime the app starts I want to shuffle the elements that are in my array, also the elements should be placed on the screen without repeating, how I can do this? I tried several extensions to shuffle my array but didn't work

I'm using swift 4.1 and Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit

struct ContainerSprite{
    let block : SKSpriteNode!

    let containers = ["Container_Circle_Blue","Container_Hexagone_Blue",
"Container_Square_Blue","Container_Star_Blue","Container_Triangle_Blue",
"Container_Circle_DBlue","Container_Hexagone_DBlue","Container_Square_DBlue",
"Container_Star_DBlue","Container_Triangle_DBlue","Container_Circle_Green",
"Container_Hexagone_Green","Container_Square_Green","Container_Star_Green",
"Container_Triangle_Green"]

    init (numContainer: Int, row: Int, col: Int , inThisScene: GameScene) {
        block = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: containers[numContainer])
        let numberOfBlocks = 12.5
        let blockScale = 0.6   
     }
}
```

This is one of the extensions I used but when I tried, it was showing elements repeated randomly

```
extension MutableCollection {
    /// Shuffles the contents of this collection.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }

        for (firstUnshuffled, unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            // Change Int in the next line to IndexDistance in < Swift 4.1
            let d: Int = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            swapAt(firstUnshuffled, i)
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array with the contents of this sequence, shuffled.
    func shuffled() -> [Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to randomize the elements of `containers`? Show what you tried. There are plenty of examples of shuffling an array in Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I want to randomize the elements of "containers" I updated my question and added the extension I used

Comment: And what problem exactly are you having?

Comment: @rmaddy the problem with this extension is that puts repeated elements of my array randomly, and I want each element to be unique at different place every time my app starts

Comment: It looks like you got that code from the duplicate I just linked. If that specific code doesn't work then look at one of the many other solutions there.

Comment: what is wrong with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994757-shuffled

Comment: Are you sure you are not constantly shuffling after you read each index?  that would cause duplicates

Comment: @pds that does not exist yet (That comes with XCode 10)